# Key combination in AutoIt

Tags: testing, autoit

I am trying to automate pressing `CTRL+O` button using `AutoIt`. I am not able to get the syntax right.Please help.Below is the code I am using.

```
WinActivate("XYZ")
Send("{LCTRL down}")
Send("{O}")
Send("{LCTRL up}")
```

What is wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [AutoIt documentation](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm), I would think that this would do it:

```
WinActivate("XYZ")
Send("^O")
```

If that doesn't work, can you comment on this answer and I will investigate and edit.